# how to make netbeans with jdk7 , java ee 6 aware?

Tags: netbeans, java-ee-6

I have installed netbeans+jdk7u6 bundle from oracle site and jdk7 is referred only by netbeans and my system has openjdk6 which i use for writing & compiling programs from command line.

If i am not wrong java ee 6 is just a spec and implementations are GlassFish AS , tomcat etc.

does installing tomcat(of course the version supported by my netbeans version) alleviate my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not shure what NB version is bundled by oracle, but there's a Java EE package of Netbeans: http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html (Java EE)

If you don't have this one (or the 'all') you can install it via **Tools -> Plugins -> *(Available Plugins)*** and select eg. **Jave EE Base** or whatever you need.

Comment: yeah i did install java EE base plugin and created a maven web project and maven automatically downloaded the glassfish AS in prescribed folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage java platforms in Netbeans using `Tools -> java platforms`.
Just manage (add or remove) java platforms and tell netbeans which one do you want to use by `right clicking on project -> properties -> compile`